# merging two data structures of different shapes

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lenses

I have two data structures with different shapes that come from two different API's. The data is in JSON format, language is JavaScript.

Array 1:

```
[ { "document" : { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "DOCUMENT_NAME_1" },
    "tooltips" : [ { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "TASK_NAME_1" }, 
                   { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "TASK_NAME_2" } ] },
  { "document" : { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "DOCUMENT_NAME_2" },
    "tooltips" : [ { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "TASK_NAME_3" }, 
                   { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "TASK_NAME_4" } ] }]
```

Array 2:

```
  [ [ { "name" : "TASK_NAME_1", "status" : "FINISHED" }, 
      { "name" : "TASK_NAME_2", "status" : "OPEN" } ],
    [ { "name" : "TASK_NAME_3", "status" : "OPEN" }, 
      { "name" : "TASK_NAME_4", "status" : "FUTURE" } ] ]
```

The elements of the tooltips field from the array 1 contain the same "name"s as elements of array 2. How can I elegantly merge "status" from the array 2 into tooltips within array 1?

I thought that lenses could be the right answer, but I'm unsure as I've never used them.

I am aware of some ways I could solve it using nested iteration and updating array 1. I am ideally looking for an approach that doesn't modify existing data structures.

Comment: So I thought it would look along the lines.
[array1, array2].zip.map(get_from_array_2(_lens?), insert_into_array_2(_lens?))

Comment: You talk about `zip`ping. Are you guaranteeing that the structure of the two arrays is the same? Or do you need to find them by the `name`?

Comment: The structure of the two arrays is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is little complex but it should work for you

```
array2.forEach(function(tooltips){
    tooltips.forEach(function(tooltip){
        for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < array1[i].tooltips.length; j++) {
                var arr1Tooltip = array1[i].tooltips[j];
                if(arr1Tooltip.name == tooltip.name)
                    arr1Tooltip.status = tooltip.status;
            };
        };        
    });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(array1));
```

Comment: It's a good working solution and is similar to that I've currently implemented. It's not one that I'm after though. I'll update my question.

Comment: Why do you mix up `forEach` loops with plain `for`-loops? Also, this *does* modify the existing data structure, which is what the OP not wanted.

Comment: @Bergi OP updated the question. Look at the previous comment. I did it for previous one.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way over engineered and not very efficient, but you can do it as with [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neelsg/7bFq6/) using recursive functions. I'm too tired to do it in a clever way.

```
var arr1 = [ { "document" : { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "DOCUMENT_NAME_1" },
    "tooltips" : [ { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "TASK_NAME_1" }, 
                   { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "TASK_NAME_2" } ] },
  { "document" : { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "DOCUMENT_NAME_2" },
    "tooltips" : [ { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "TASK_NAME_3" }, 
                   { "html" : "some_html", "name" : "TASK_NAME_4" } ] }];

var arr2 = [ [ { "name" : "TASK_NAME_1", "status" : "FINISHED" }, 
      { "name" : "TASK_NAME_2", "status" : "OPEN" } ],
    [ { "name" : "TASK_NAME_3", "status" : "OPEN" }, 
      { "name" : "TASK_NAME_4", "status" : "FUTURE" } ] ];

var findStatus = function(name, searchArray) {
    var r = '';
    if (typeof searchArray === 'object') {
        if ("name" in searchArray && "status" in searchArray) {
            if (searchArray.name == name) {
                return searchArray.status;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        } else {
            for (var i in searchArray) {
                r = findStatus(name, searchArray[i]);
                if (r != '') {
                    return r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return '';
};

var updateStatus = function(arrToUpdate, arrWithStatus) {
    var copy = $.extend(true, {}, arrToUpdate);
    var r = '';
    if (typeof copy === 'object') {
        if ("name" in copy) {
            r = findStatus(copy.name, arrWithStatus);
            if (r != '') {
                copy.status = r;
            }
        } else {
            for (var i in copy) {
                copy[i] = updateStatus(copy[i], arrWithStatus);
            }
        }
    }
    return copy;
};

var arr3 = updateStatus(arr1, arr2); // Final combined array
```

I added the `var copy = $.extend(true, {}, arrToUpdate);` line so that it will do a deep copy and not modify the original array, as a result, it requires jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data structure is nested, you will need two `zip.map`/`zipWith`s:

```
zip(array1, array2).map(function([obj, tooltips]) { // ES6 destructuring syntax
    return {
        document: obj.document,
        tooltips: zip(obj.tooltips, tooltips).map(function([tooltip, extender]) {
            return {
                html: tooltip.html,
                name: tooltip.name,
                status: extender.status
            };
        })
    };
})
```

If you don't like to repeat those object literal structures, you might be able to use some copying function; for example

```
extend({}, document, {tooltips:…})
extend({}, tooltip, extender);
```

You also might use a lenses library like https://github.com/DrBoolean/lenses or https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-lenses for that, but I'm not sure whether that's worth the effort - the above code only needs underscore/lodash.

To get around the inner `zipWith`, you would need a `Traversal` lens (I assume you're familiar with [this article](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html)), but I haven't yet seen a JavaScript library that offers such.

Comment: If you're unsure how to use lenses, choose a library and I'll make an example of what I mean.